# Google Drive API Cannot See Files in Shared Folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I have created a Service Account and made this account (XXXX@XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com) be a Manager in a Shared Drive.

I am able to retrieve the shared folder ID by running `service.drives().list(pageSize=10).execute()`

But if I run:

```
folder_id = '0ACNaJE1nx6YwXXXXXXX' # Same folder ID as above
query = "'%s' in parents" % folder_id
response = service.files().list(q=query, spaces='drive', fields='files(id, name, parents)').execute()
```

It returns `{'files': []}` even though the shared folder contains some files. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list from the specific folder in the shared Drive using googleapis for python.
- Your `service` in your script has the permission for retrieving the file list from the shared drive.

In this case, how about including `includeItemsFromAllDrives=True`, `supportsAllDrives=True` and `corpora="allDrives"` in the query parameter of the method of files.list in Drive API? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
folder_id = '0ACNaJE1nx6YwXXXXXXX' # Same folder ID as above
query = "'%s' in parents" % folder_id
response = service.files().list(q=query, pageSize=1000, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True, corpora="allDrives", fields='files(id, name, parents)').execute()
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that you have the permission for retrieving the file metadata from the shared drive. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: Very helpful! With `corpora="allDrives"` I got way more files than I wanted, but the other settings were exactly what I needed.